# ¿Cómo puedo configurar mi servidor para enviar mail correctamente?

Tags: ubuntu

Tengo un servidor en el cuál el usuario solicita darse de alta en un portal y envío un mail con los datos.

Este email siempre llega al spam, pero es un email con un usuario y una contraseña, nada más.

¿Como podría configurar el servidor para que llegue a la bandeja de entrada?

Es un Ubuntu Server 15.10.

Comment: [**comprueba aqui**](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) que no tengas el servidor de correo en ninguna blacklist, probablemente sea ese el motivo por el que los correos llegan a la carpeta de SPAM

Comment: No no, no está en black list. Lo he vuelto a comprobar por si acaso y nada, yo creo que es alguna configuración del servidor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te recomiendo que utilices [Email Server Test](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test), que es una herramienta perfecta para este tipo de casos.

Básicamente envías un correo a `test@allaboutspam.com` y te contestan con un informe detallado de qué está pasando (y será fácil de resolver). Lo que mira esta herramienta es:

- **HELO Greeting** - Si tienes un problema aquí, mira [este link](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~rickert/cf/bad-ehlo.html).
- **Reverse DNS** - Si tienes un problema aquí, mira [este link](http://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx).
- **DNSBL (RBL)** - Si tienes un problema aquí, mira [este link](http://www.dnsbl.info/).
- **SPF** - Si tienes un problema aquí, mira [este link](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html).
- **Domain Keys** - Si tienes un problema aquí, mira [este link](http://dkimvalidator.com/).
- **SPAMAssassin Content Checks** - Si tienes un problema aquí, mira [este link](http://www.mailingcheck.com/spamassassin-score/).
- **BATV (Bounce Address Tag Validation)** - Si tienes un problema aquí, mira [este link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_Address_Tag_Validation).
- **Greylisting** - Si tienes un problema aquí, mira [este link](http://www.greylisting.org/test/).
- **URIBL** - Si tienes un problema aquí, mira [este link](http://uribl.com/).

---

Además, como indica [Jordi Castilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17463/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-configurar-mi-servidor-para-enviar-mail-correctamente/17465#comment28512_17463), puedes mirar en [MXtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) si tu IP/Dominio está en alguna blacklist (aunque ya se mira el BlackList y el GreyList en el apartado anterior)

Comment: Estaba en una blacklist, pero conseguí quitarlo. Ahora sigue dando el mismo problema. El envío de correos se realiza siempre desde cuentas corporativos p. ej: hola@miempresa.es y siempre llegan a spam. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Pueden existir varios motivos por los que un correo llega a una bandeja de SPAM en vez de a la bandeja de entrada sin estar dentro de ninguna lista negra.

- **Violación de políticas de seguridad de correo (SPF, DKIM y/o DMARC):** Si usas como remitente una cuenta de correo de un dominio que usa este tipo de seguridad, cuando llegue a un destinatario va a reconocer que tu servidor no es un servidor de confianza y lo va a marcar como SPAM.  Por ejemplo, gmail, hotmail, live, yahoo, etc usan estas protecciones, no puedes usar envío directo de correos electrónicos de estos dominios desde tu propio servidor. **Solución:** No uses la función `mail()` de PHP, usa una librería como PHPMailer que soporte envío por SMTP/S y configura el servidor saliente de tu proveedor de correo, no uses el MTA de tu servidor web.
- **Violación de alguno de los RFC relacionados con SMTP y/o MIME:** Si no usas correctamente las cabeceras, si no usas la codificación de caracteres correcta, formas correctamente el mensaje SMTP, etc, puedes ser "detectado" por aplicaciones anti-spam como un mensaje de SPAM. **Solución:** PHPMailer podría ayudarte con este tema, tú le indicas el HTML, la versión del contenido en texto plano, las cabeceras adicionales que desees usar y él monta el mensaje correctamente.

Si sabes usar spamassasin te recomendaría pasarle un lint a un mensaje de correo que hayas enviado para averiguar qué reglas de anti-spam estás cumpliendo para tratar de arreglarlas o evitarlas.

Lo siento, pero sin código ni ejemplo del contenido de correo ni ninguna información más no puedo ayudarte en más profundidad.

Answer (score 0):

Al no dar muchos detalles de como lo estás haciendo, me hace suponer que estás enviando los correos por `mail()`, de ser así, una buena función para enviar correos y que no lleguen a spam, es usar `PHPMailer` [Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), tus correos serían enviados con autenticación y usando SSL, evitando llegar a la carpeta SPAM.